# Remove schema name from createView tag

Tags: mysql, view, liquibase

So I'm just getting started using Liquibase, and I'm trying to add it to an existing project that already has a 200+ table database set-up. I've successfully created a changeLog.xml of the existing database.

However, I run into an issue with how views are handled.  The content of the  tag includes the fully qualified column names ([schema].[table].[column]). This creates a problem because I'm hoping to be able to use Liquibase to set-up different versions of the same database (dev, testing, production), and those databases will have different name (e.g. application_dev, application_testing, application_production). If I create the changeLog.xml using my development database, then I'll get something similar to the following for the views:

```
<createView replaceIfExists="true" viewName="view_clients">
  select `application_dev.clients.clientid','application_dev.clients.client_name' from `application_dev`
</createView>
```

So when I go to use this changeLog to create the `application_testing` database, I get the error

```
Error executing SQL CREATE VIEW: Table `application_testing.clients` doesn't exist
```

So is there a way around this issue, or am I trying to make Liquibase do something it wasn't designed for?

Answer (score 1):

You might look into using properties at the top of the changelog that are specific to the environment you are deploying into, similar to what is described in this answer:

[Database Migration with Liquibase using different DBMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619196/database-migration-with-liquibase-using-different-dbms)

In your case, rather than using properties whose values differ depending on the dbms, you could have properties whose values differ depending on the context, which is a Liquibase concept that is designed for just this sort of problem.

So the properties at the top of the changelog might look like this:

```
<property name="schemaName" value="application_dev" context="dev"/>
<property name="schemaName" value="application_test" context="test"/>
<property name="schemaName" value="application_prod" context="production"/>
```

Then you can have changeSets like this:

```
<createView replaceIfExists="true" viewName="view_clients">
  select `${schemaName}.clients.clientid','${schemaName}.clients.client_name' from `${schemaName}`
</createView>
```